# How to show error message instantly when files not of image types using fileupload jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using `jQuery File Upload Plugin 5.21` to upload files to my site. My need is to show error message instantly when a file type not like image is added(by checking file extension). how to use built in function to check this operation like `_onSend` `_beforeSend` but not aware of using it.
(If possible can show a demo?).Thankx in advance

Comment: You want code for this?

Comment: @geek if their is any example. it will be more helpful. thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code.

- JavaScript

`add: function (e, data) {
        var goUpload = true;
        var uploadFile = data.files[0];
        if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
            common.notifyError('You must select an image file or your message.......');
            goUpload = false;
        }if (goUpload == true) {
            data.submit();
        }
    },`

Comment: i was trying to use _onAdd. i'll check this. thank you for your ans